# remote login to ubuntu server via SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 Ubuntu machines. First one (A) is my local machine, second one (B) is a gateway to the third (C) Ubuntu server. I can SSH from my local machine, A, to B and then SSH from B to C. I can't SSH from A to C directly.

What I need is to remotely log (graphical) into C from B? and if possible from A? I'm no network guy and the tunneling concept and port 3389 is confusing me.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You did not explain why port 3389 was confusing you and why you have to use it? I guess it is equivalent the port 7722 from the well described example below? Maybe the question would be clearer then to some down voters (actually I voted you up, because I found the solution via this question! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusing or not, you need tunneling. The easiest:

```
ssh -L 7722:address.of.C:22 address.of.B
```

will log you into B. At the same time, it will set up a tunnel between the current machine's port 7722 (can be any unused port over 1024, I arbitrarily selected 7722) and C's port 22 (the ssh port). Then, in another terminal,

```
ssh -X -p 7722 localhost
```

will open a SSH connection to your local port 7722, which is being tunneled to C's 22. It is functionally equivalent to `ssh address.of.C` while the above tunnel exists.

When you are done, just exit the second connection to leave C, then exit the first connection to deconstruct the tunnel.

---

If you don't have two terminals to work with, it is a bit more complex since you need a way to refer to the tunnel in order to be able to close it later.

```
ssh -fNM -S /tmp/tunnel.B.to.C.control 7722:address.of.C:22 address.of.B

ssh -X -p 7722 localhost

ssh -O exit -S /tmp/tunnel.B.to.C.control address.of.B
```

Here, `/tmp/tunnel.B.to.C.control` is an arbitrary name of file in a location where you can create a file. The first command sets up a tunnel and exits (instead of logging in), but stays in memory and records its activities in the named file. The last command then releases the tunnel, the memory and the file.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend me a nice tutorial about SSH covering the topic?